# Get an Enumerator for Generic Object

Tags: c#, generics, enumerator

I have made a thorough search for an answer and have not found one.

I want to write a method that translates an object into a dictionary object. When this method is called, the specific type of the input object will be provided.

Here is what I have thus far.

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> TranslateFormData<T>(Object form)
{
    T formData = (T)Convert.ChangeType(form, typeof(T));
    Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> pairs = formData.GetEnumerator();

    while (pairs.MoveNext())
    {
        //Code left out for brevity
    }

    return data;
}
```

The usage would be something like this

```
Dictionary<string,string> data = FormData.TranslateFormData<FormCollection>(formData);
```

However, in the "TranslateFormData" method, the line

```
IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> pairs = formData.GetEnumerator ( );
```

produces the following error:

> 'T' does not contain a definition for 'GetEnumerator' and no extension method 'GetEnumerator' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I specify the Type for object form in order to obtain an enumerator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, just make the parameter of type `T` to avoid the cast:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> TranslateFormData<T> ( T formData )
```

Then you can add a [*generic constraint*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) so that `T` must implement `IEnumerable< KeyValuePair< string, string > >`:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> TranslateFormData<T> ( T formData ) 
    where T : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    // don't need this line due to above
    //T formData = ( T )Convert.ChangeType ( form, typeof ( T ) );

    // rest the same.
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, but then created a different error. While related to this, I will ask a different question specific to the next issue. Thank you

Comment: Actually now that I think of it, you can just have a method: `public static Dictionary<string,string> TranslateFromData( IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string> formData )` and not use generics at all.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, I would like to keep it as generic as possible. This function may be useful for translating other types. However, for my specific situation I will try that. I want to avoid having to overload if at all possible

Comment: @PaulStoner there would be no functional difference. With both the solution in the answer and the comment you can only call the function with a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`

Comment: OK That makes complete sense. Maybe [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764146/data-binding-from-formcollection-to-model) this question will shed some light on my particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with what you are asking, you are basically trying to force an object to implement the IEnumerable interface. 
The compiler does not know whether the object you are trying to convert will definetly be of type IEnumerable.

There for, you must declare the generic object as an object implementing the specified interface.

just add this line into your function declaration's end.

```
where T : IEnumerable
```