# Data Binding from FormCollection to Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, generics

I am trying to bind data received from my view to a specific model. I want to translate the form data into a dictionary object. This is accomplished using a generic method I developed, TranslateFormData. This is where I am having issues.

Here is the controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SubmitDecision ( FormCollection formData )
{
    Dictionary<string, string> data = FormData.TranslateFormData ( formData );
    TPDispatcherNetClient client = new TPDispatcherNetClient ( );

    *Additional code left out for brevity*        

    return View ( );
}
```

This line, `Dictionary<string, string> data = FormData.TranslateFormData ( formData );`, is causing me issues. Here is the code for TranslateFormData:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> TranslateFormData<T> ( T form ) where T : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string> ( );
    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> pairs = form.GetEnumerator ( );

    return data;
}
```

Passing in the FormCollection is producing the following error:

> The type 'System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'TranslateFormData(T)'. There is no implicit >reference conversion from 'System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'

How can I accomplish this? I want avoid changing TranslateFormData to accept a specific type and then overloading based on all expected types if at all possible.

> EDIT
>   Since initially writing this question I have modified my translation method accordingly:

```
public static CustomerDecisionRequest TranslateFormData<T> ( T form ) where T : NameValueCollection, IEnumerable
{
    CustomerDecisionRequest request = new CustomerDecisionRequest ( );
    IEnumerator enumerator = formData.GetEnumerator ( );

    return request;
}
```

So, while the above questions stands, does this modification make sense and is it appropriate?

Comment: No offense, but what in heaven are you doing? If you want a dictionary, accept a dictionary as your action parameter and let the modelbinder work it out.

Comment: @ChrisPratt no offense taken. I am very new to the whole MVC thing and unfortunately I need to use MVC for a complex process. Basically, the above code is in my controller. All I want to do is get the posted data and convert it to a class that is in a WCF service. I also want to be able to utilize the "translate" method elsewhere in the same project without having to overload.

Comment: If your class is say `Employee` and the controls in your view are rendered using strongly typed helpers e.g. `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)` then when you post back to `public ActionResult Edit(Employee model)` then the model is bound for you. You don't (and should not) need to _translate_ anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the comments. The approach I was taking was based on ignorance. I was able to get my view to post the correct data, using the correct model, back to my controller. In addition, I need no custom/special binding.

My problem lied in not setting up my model correctly. I was just specifying public fields instead of automatic public properties. Once I made that change, everything else fell into place